# Reassign Makefile Parameters

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In the current system, there was a ghetto hack to initiate a parallel build for the system.  For instance, to call a parallel make required `make JOBS=8` instead of `make -j8`.  I have since fixed the makefile, however there are a lot of previous dependencies on the `JOBS` flags within scripts that call make.  I was hoping to recursively call make as a workaround as such:

```
ifdef JOBS
%:
  $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) JOBS= -j$(JOBS)
endif
```

This has some odd behavior though.  It will first call `make JOBS= -j8` as it should, but after this rule is completed it seems to go on and rebuild everything again that is in `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`.

```
#Example
TARGETS = lib0 lib1 lib2
ifdef JOBS
%:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) -j$(JOBS) JOBS=
endif

all: $(TARGETS)

lib%:
    @echo g++ $@
```

Cmd: `make JOBS=8`.

This is fine for most rules, however it keeps wasting time rebuilding PHONY rules, so this should be fixed.  Is there a way to completely reroute a `make JOBS=N` command to `make -j$(JOBS)` without executing any other rules redundantly in either scope?  (meaning nothing executes except a submake in `make JOBS=N`, and the submake is only called once with all `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` at once.)

EDIT: I would also like to avoid large `ifdef; else; endif` statements, at the very most putting a self contained one at the top of the file.  I'm starting to think the solution may require something like that though:

```
TARGETS = lib0 lib1 lib2

ifdef JOBS
%: unique_make
    @echo $@ built > /dev/null

.PHONY: unique_make
unique_make:
    $(MAKE) $(MAKECMDGOALS) -j$(JOBS) JOBS=
else

all: $(TARGETS)

lib%:
    @echo g++ $@
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GNU make, you can modify the make flags within a Makefile. Why not try something like this:

```
ifdef JOBS
MAKEFLAGS+=-j$(JOBS)
endif
```

Comment: The extent of my derps cannot even be expressed in words.  Thank you sir.

Comment: Note this will only enable parallelism on the current instance of make if you're using GNU make 4.0 or above, I think.